# how to stop framer motion animation run on every re rendering

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion, react-animations

I am using framer motion for animation and my problem is the animation triggers with every re rendering on my page. the behavior that I want is to animation only once on page entering or reloading not by re rendering. here is my component:

```
const WrapperLoginFlow = () => {

     const MotionCard = motion(Card);


     return (

        <MotionCard
           initial={{ scale: 0, opacity: 0 }}
           animate={{ scale: 1, opacity: 1 }}
           transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        >
           <div>
             something
           </div>

        </MotionCard>
 )};
```

I have some state in this component that might cause re rendering the page and it cause the animation starts when ever my page re renders. how can I stop this?

Comment: Did you try to move `const MotionCard = motion(Card);`out of your component ?

Comment: Thanks my friend! that worked could you please write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `const MotionCard = motion(Card);` out of your component.

If it is in your component, at every render, it will create again the motion component and trigger the animation.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy with React 18. Use a hook. Use useEffect hook with an empty dependency array and run your animations in the hook. Also remember that framer motion has utility functions for animations as well. Check their documentation.